# JS: Replace innerHTML of tags

Tags: javascript, string, replace, tags

My application dynamically gets HTML code from my website and saves it as a String.

Here's an example:

```
Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.com">Click Here</a>
Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.com">Click Somewhere</a>
Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.com">sdfsdf</a>
Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.com">djmhfhb</a>
Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.com">fgbnfgn</a>
```

What I now need is a script that takes all the  tags and replaces their innerHTML with "LINK". The result should be:

```
Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.com">LINK</a>
Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.com">LINK</a>
Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.com">LINK</a>
Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.com">LINK</a>
Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.com">LINK</a>
```

I'd usually use jQuery like this:

```
$(a).html = "Link"
```

But I don't want to remove the innerHTML of the links in my app but those inside the String which contains the HTML of my website.

I don't use PHP. I use any kind of JS that helps me out.
Any ideas? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

this is how you do that with jQuery:

```
$('a').text('LINK');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

For instance:

```
$("a").text("LINK");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in js script 
give id on anchar tag

```
<a href="www.google.com" id="hello" />Click<a>
```

and use like this

```
$('#hello').html('LINK');
```

or

```
$('a').text('LINK');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why you would not want to use jQuery .html() or .text() in your app but manipulate the string containing the html instead?

Doing that will require some kind of Regex pattern like this

```
var pattern = "<a .*?href=['""](.+?)['""].*?>(.+?)</a>";
```

and then use string.Replace passing in a RegExp object

Something like

```
var regex = new RegExp(pattern);
"yourString".replace(regex , "LINK");
```

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you're getting those markups **as string**, not DOM fragment, you can try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/YVb5k/

```
var str="HTML markup";
if ((new DOMParser()).parseFromString("", "text/html")) {
    var html = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/html");
} else {
    var html = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
    html.body.innerHTML = str;
}
var as = html.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    as[i].innerHTML = "LINK";
}
console.log(html.body.innerHTML);
```

Works only in IE>=9, though.